# How to round number based on decimal point provided in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, math, rounding

```
Input Number : 3266.528
deciaml Point: 1
output for decimal point (1) : 3266.5
output for decimal point (2) : 3266.53
output for decimal point (3) : 3266.528
output for decimal point (4) : 3266.5280
```

How to round numbers based on decimal point given as above. Based on input number and decimal point, I would like to get the number rounded as above

Comment: Take a look at the decimal pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular way in javascript is simply the following :

```
const num = 3266.528;
const result = Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
```

where the 100 will round to 2 decimal places, 1000 for 3 places, etc..  You can parameterize and make use of `Math.pow(10, idx)` if you'd like e.g.

```
const round = (n, dec) => (Math.round(n * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec));
```

Answer (score 1):

use .toFixed() on the number. The parameter you give will determine the number of digits to return after the decimal point.

```
let num = 3266.5390
console.log(num.toFixed(2)) // answer will be 3266.54
console.log(num.toFixed(3)) // answer will be 3266.539
```

Comment: Not quite - console.log(num.toFixed(2)) -> `3266.54`  But this is the right way to round to x decimals.